# Javascript How can I extract the ID as INT from a URL?

Tags: javascript, jquery, url

I have url of the type:

```
localhost/Support/My-DNN-Module-Name/ID/133
```

I need to always extract the ID value at the end, in this case 133.
This is what I am doing currently to extract  it:

```
if (url) {
      // try tograb number as int from url
      var intValue = url.match( /\d+/ );
                if (intValue) {
                    console.log("converted url to int value and the result is: " + intValue);                   
                }
                else {
                    console.log("could not convert url to int value");
                }
}
```

Obviously this is not very good in case the URL contains other number(s), for example in the case that the localhost is entered as an actual ip address.

How can I target only the last part after ID and grab whatever number might be there please, ideally independent of what the url might look like before it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the number you want always ends the string, you can add `$` for the matched digits to be at the very end:

```js
const str = 'localhost/12345/Support/My-DNN-Module-Name/ID/133';
const match = str.match(/\d+$/);
if (match) {
  console.log(match[0]);
}
```